# std::vector<char> VS std::string, which one is faster?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, vector, cellular-automata

I've been messing around with cellular-automata for a while now, and the way I chose to implement them is by creating a 2D vector of cells, where each cell was initially a vector of integers itself *(because I want each cell to store more than one value)*, which I later changed to short unsigned integers, and then to chars, because I realized the smallest data type is more than enough for my needs...

I'm currently looking for ways to improve performance, and it got me thinking, would it be better optimization-wise if I replaced the vector of chars with a string?

Knowing that the entire matrix always has a fixed size, meaning the size of the 2D grid as well as that of each cell is allocated from the beginning and is unchanging for the duration of the program's runtime:

Which one is faster to access? Modify? Copy? Or preform general operations on?

Also, I know I said everything has a fixed size, but just for future reference, according to my surface-level knowledge of vectors, a vector has to be re-allocated everytime you push_back() a new element into it, is that the case with strings?

Comment: When you want to know which is faster you need to measure.

Comment: If the size is fixed and known at *compile* time, consider using `std::array` rather than `vector`.

Comment: Overall, `std::vector` offers the same perofmance as `std::string`. The difference between two containers is mostly in interface functions.

Comment: vector will probably be faster since it doesn't do SSO like string does.  You really should benchmark first though.  Making performance decisions without facts is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: there is no general answer. Without a real use case it is hard to set up realistic benchmarks to know which performs better. You are in the fortunate situation that you already have a working application and that you can replace one with the other to see which performs better.

Comment: Re: "a vector has to be re-allocated everytime you push_back()" -- that's not correct. vector typically allocates some extra space, and when you push back you insert into that space.

Comment: If you add the code you have to your question we could provide better performance recommendations rather than guessing.

Comment: *a vector has to be re-allocated everytime you push_back()* -- Any vector implementation that does that would be highly questionable, maybe even laughable (and unfortunately, would still be valid implementation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which one is faster?

Depends. Either one, depending on how you use them. You can find out whether one is measurably faster than the other by... measuring.

They both use fundamentally the same abstract data structure, and have the same asymptotical complexity for all operations.

> according to my surface-level knowledge of vectors, a vector has to be re-allocated everytime you push_back()

Your knowledge is incorrect. A `std::vector` has to only be reallocated *when the **capacity** of the vector is exceeded*, which isn't everytime you push_back. Same appilies to `std::string`

Answer (score -2):

From this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/25581325/15824294 I think we can observe that string is faster than vector with both g++ and clang++

Comment: no. From that answer we can see that `string` performs faster than `std::vector<char>` for that one particular benchmark. Not more, not less. The Q&A is actually a nice example for how unreliable such extrapolation is. Didn't you notice that the question and the accepted answer have "contradicting" results?

Comment: Actually, any difference in execution time of a microbenchmark less than a few,  say, 5% or even 10%, is meaningless. This time can be affected by many factor beyond the program's control, like whether other processes are running and compete for computer's resources.